# Reproduce findDrawdowns and maxDrawdown functions in R given return series

Tags: programming, drawdown, maximum-drawdown

Is there any formula to calculate all drawdowns (and maximum drawdown) directly from return series? Or is it always necessary to convert the returns into implied "prices" first and then proceed with finding drawdowns?

Here is an example (done in Excel):

```
Date     Returns     100,00      Drawdown 
01.02.2000  0,30     100,30      -     
01.03.2000  2,60     102,91      -     
01.04.2000  1,10     104,04      -     
01.05.2000  -1,00    103,00     -1,00   
01.06.2000  1,50     104,54      -     
01.07.2000  2,50     107,16      -     
01.08.2000  1,60     108,87      -     
01.09.2000  6,70     116,17      -     
01.10.2000  -1,40    114,54     -1,40   
01.11.2000  4,00     119,12      -     
01.12.2000  -0,50    118,53     -0,50   
01.01.2001  8,10     128,13      -     
01.02.2001  4,00     133,25      -     
01.03.2001  -3,70    128,32     -3,70   
01.04.2001  -6,10    120,49     -9,57   
01.05.2001  1,70     122,54     -8,04   
01.06.2001  -4,90    116,54     -12,54   
01.07.2001  -2,20    113,97     -14,47   
01.08.2001  7,00     121,95     -8,48   
01.09.2001  5,80     129,03     -3,17   
01.10.2001  -6,50    120,64     -9,47   
01.11.2001  2,40     123,53     -7,29   
01.12.2001  -0,50    122,92     -7,76   
01.01.2002  -0,90    121,81     -8,59
```

I am taking the current "price", then subtracting from this "price" the maximum "price" between the inititation date and the current date, then dividing this difference by that max "price". And finally, the drawdown is the minimum between this result and 0:

```
=MIN((C11-MAX($C$3:C11))/MAX($C$3:C11);0)*100
```

Max drawdown would be the minimum among the drawdowns.

I would like to do this in R. Preferably without creating the "price" table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it without prices. But creating such a "price" series
is very easy in R.

```
r <- rnorm(10, sd = 0.01)  ## returns
cumprod(1 + r)             ## => 'prices'
```

You can then easily compute the maximum drawdown:

```
require("NMOF")
drawdown(cumprod(1 + r))
```

In fact, you may not even need a package for computing drawdowns, since it is also very easy in R.

```
v <- cumprod(1 + r)
1 - v/cummax(v)         ## drawdown
max(1 - v/cummax(v))    ## max. drawdown
```